# If have time since epoch, how can I turn it to a date? c++

Tags: c++, time

I want to save a file with the date of it's creation in its name. I get the time since epoch that the client got when it created it. I want to turn it to the date of its creation.

Comment: Have you looked at the C Time Library (`<ctime>`)? Or any other libraries for time conversions? It might help if you do some more research and then explain what you've looked into and what's still not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/ctime/) as follows:

```
int main ()
{
  time_t a= 1492947397;
  std::cout<<"The time is: %s"<< ctime (&a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I found out what the problem was. The value I entered into the time_t type variable was the milliseconds since epoch. Ctime is supposed to get the seconds since epoch

Comment: @L.Zelik: Would you like to have the milliseconds precision in the name?  [Here's a C++11 library that will do that](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).